# Windows Search SQL: Semicolon in LIKE statement causes exception (E_FAIL 0x80004005)

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, search

I am querying the windows search engine about some documents in my ASP.NET web application.
I'm looking for all documents which title contains the string "; IT" (besides other conditions, stripped from the following example).
I'm going through ADO.NET, so my code looks like this one (stripped some unimportant details):

```
var connString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;" + 
                 "Extended Properties='Application=Windows';";
var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

conn.Open();
StringWriter wSql = new StringWriter();
wSql.WriteLine("SELECT System.Title, System.Filename, System.Keywords, " + 
               "System.Size, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.ItemUrl, " +
               "System.Search.Rank, System.DateCreated, System.DateModified " + 
               "FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE System.Title LIKE '%; IT%'");

var cmd = new OleDbCommand(wSql.ToString(), conn);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
var result = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(result, "doc");  // <== HERE THE RUNTIME EXPLODES
```

When i run this code, an exception is thrown at the last line, with code "E_FAIL 0x80004005". If i remove the semicolon from the LIKE statement, all works like a charm, but obviously i do not have the expected results, since i really really need only documents in which the title correspond to the given string.

I tried searching for reserved characters and/or escaping in Windows Search SQL, but without luck.

Any idea?

Thanks and regards,

Claudio

Comment: Did you try escaping the semicolon with square brackets? `[;]`

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Windows Search API doesn't support the Like operator.